# module.exports.PrimaryNavigation = connect(selector, authActions, modalActions)(PrimaryNavigation); not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code working right now

```
module.exports.BasePrimaryNavigation = PrimaryNavigation;
module.exports.PrimaryNavigation = connect(selector, authActions)(PrimaryNavigation);
```

I need to add this code:

```
module.exports.BasePrimaryNavigation = PrimaryNavigation;
module.exports.PrimaryNavigation = connect(selector, modalActions)(PrimaryNavigation);
```

I've tried putting them on two lines and tried using `modalActions` after `authActions` in the first code I provided. When I put them on two lines with modalActions as the second line and authActions as the first, I get the modal to work. But when I put it first, it wont work. Meaning the authActions isn't working. What can I do to get both of these to work?

Also I've now tried this:

```
module.exports.BasePrimaryNavigation = PrimaryNavigation;
module.exports = {
  PrimaryNavigation: connect(selector, authActions)(PrimaryNavigation),
  SecondaryNavigation: connect(selector, modalActions)(PrimaryNavigation),
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two exports with the same name (PrimaryNavigation). 
You're essentially doing this:

```
module.exports = {
  PrimaryNavigation: connect(selector, authActions)(PrimaryNavigation),
  PrimaryNavigation: connect(selector, modalActions)(PrimaryNavigation),
}
```

But you need to do something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  PrimaryNavigation: connect(selector, authActions)(PrimaryNavigation),
  SecondaryNavigation: connect(selector, modalActions)(PrimaryNavigation),
}
```

You cannot have multiple module.exports, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16631064/declare-multiple-module-exports-in-node-js)

Comment: Just use one module.exports, not multiple. And please provide an example how you import.