# Export multiple files as single module in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is a simple example of what I'm trying to achieve:

**foo.js :**

```
module.exports.one = function(params) { */ stuff */ }
```

**bar.js :**

```
module.exports.two = function(params) { */ stuff */ }
```

**stuff.js:**

```
const foo = require('Path/foo');
const bar = require('Path/bar');
```

*I want to do :*

**otherFile.js:**

```
stuff = require('Path/stuff');

stuff.one(params);
stuff.two(params);
```

I do not want to do [in stuff.js]

```
module.exports = {
one : foo.one,
two: bar.two
}
```

The solution I came with is :

```
const files = ['path/foo', 'path/bar']

module.exports =   files
    .map(f => require(f))
    .map(f => Object.keys(f).map(e => ({ [e]: f[e] })))
    .reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), [])
    .reduce((a, b) => Object.assign(a, b), {})
```

or uglier/shorter :

```
module.exports = files
  .map(f => require(f))
  .reduce((a, b) => Object.assign(a, ...Object.keys(b).map(e => ({ [e]: b[e] }))));
```

It feels "hackish".

Is there a cleaner way to do this ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

it works this way:

**stuff.js**

```
module.exports = Object.assign(
    {},
    require('./foo'),
    require('./bar'),
);
```

or if [Object Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-TW/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) is supported:

```
module.exports = {
    ...require('./foo'),
    ...require('./bar'),
};
```

**OtherFiles.js**

```
var stuff = require('./stuff');

stuff.one();
stuff.two();
```

Comment: Link does not work.

Answer (score -1):

```
import * as stuff from "Path";  
import {foo,bar} from "Path";
```

you can still do the same in export:

```
export function foo(){};
export function bar(){};
```

Comment: The OP is not using an ES6 transpiler.