# Exported functions are not showing after import in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, async-await, require

I'm trying to import some async-await functions from a file. However, it seems that none of the exports become visible after importing.  I'm only seeing this issue with asyc-await. As far as I can see, I did the same thing with normal function and it seems to work okay.

The file I'm trying to import is  `helper.ts` with code like:

```
 // some dependencies like below:
 import mydriver from "driver";

 const driver = mydriver.driver(
    // connection settings
 );

 module.exports = {
   myFunction: async (arg) => {
     const session = driver.session();
     var result = await session.writeTransaction(
       // a query
     );
     session.close();
     return result;
   }
}
```

Then in another file I import this like:

```
import helper = require("./helper");

// Below line throws error
var result = helper.myFunction(arg);
```

The error is

`Property 'myFunction' does not exist on type 'typeof "/mydirectory/helper"'`

Comment: I suspect it's because you are mixing ESModule syntax with Node's commonJS / require syntax. Does it work if you replace the import with require?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
import helper = require("./helper");
```

should be:

```
const helper = require('./helper');
```

It looks like you will possibly have multiple functions to export, in which case this alternate syntax for assigning to `module.exports` is available as discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/38174623/8954866

```
   const privateFn = () => { }

   module.exports = {
      async myFunction (arg) {
        // method body
        return result;
      },

      async Foo () {
        // method body
        privateFn()
        this.myFunction("bar")
      }
    }
```