# Multiple exports from react.js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react.js file MyComponent that has this at the end:
`module.exports = MyComponent`, where `MyComponent` is a function defined in the file.

What if I want to export ANOTHER function: `MyHelperComponent` from the same file, so that another react component from another react.js file may use `MyHelperComponent` directly ?

So my question is: how do I export a function that is not the 'main' component of the module ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Declare multiple module.exports in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16631064/declare-multiple-module-exports-in-node-js)

Comment: Did you try google? https://create-react-app.dev/docs/importing-a-component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only export one value from a module.

If you need to use multiple values outside it, then you need to group them somehow. Typically you would put them in an object and then export that object.

```
module.exports = { MyComponent, MyHelperComponent };
```

And then:

```
const MyComponent = require("./mymodule.js").MyComponent;
const MyHelperComponent = require("./mymodule.js").MyHelperComponent;
```

or

```
const mymodule = require("./mymodule.js")
const MyComponent = mymodule.MyComponent;
const MyHelperComponent = mymodule.MyHelperComponent;
```

or

```
const {MyComponent, MyHelperComponent} = require("./mymodule.js");
```

---

That said, it is usual to structure code on a one-component-per-module basis, so you might want to rethink doing this in the first place.

Comment: So the answer is that you actually can export more than one value from a module?

Comment: @AmarSyla — No. If you export an object, then the object is the value that is exported.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this:

```
//...function defs here

MyComponent.helper = MyHelperComponent
module.exports = MyComponent
```

And then just access `MyComponent.helper(args)` to call the helper function.

Answer (score -1):

You can export like this: `export { component1, component2 }`
And use like this: `import { component1, component2 } from './url'`
or 

`import * as components from './url'
<components.component1 />`

Hope helpful...